# How to start an app with an activated keyboard and a courser in a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want that my app starts with the keyboard and a courser in my UITextView, so that the user can instantly start to write. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your text view the -becomeFirstResponder message in your viewController's viewDidAppear: method.